# Play framework how can I put a name to my Json set

Tags: java, json, playframework

I am just learning the play framework(Java) 2.40 and going through the Json examples and was wondering how can you put a name to my Json set? This is what I have..

```
    public static Result jsontry() {

    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
      result.put("1","one");
    result.put("2","two");
    return ok(result);
}
```

which returns **["1":"one","2":"two"]** I am trying to name this set "Numbers" . JsonObject and JsonArray are deprecated in Play framework 2.40 so I can not use that any suggestions would be great. I got the code above from this documentation
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaJsonRequests

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON output you want? I think you're wanting something like: `{"numbers": {"1": "one", "2": "two"}}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
ObjectNode responseNode = nodeFactory.objectNode();
ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("1","one");
    result.put("2","two");
responseNode.put("numbers", result);
 return ok(responseNode);
```

Try this out.
Or you can use simple java hashmap. set the data as  and return the map as json.